# Stop Gwibber and Empathy from scrolling to new messages

Tags: gwibber, irc

Gwibber and Empathy constantly scrolls to a new message as soon as they arrive, making it hard to read older messages, especially on IRC.

Is there a way to tell Gwibber and Empathy to not jump to a new message as soon as it arrives?

Comment: Do you mean Empathy or Gwibber? Gwibber is a twitter (and identica?) client. Empathy is the instant messenger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bug ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/327172 ) filed for this, but it has since been fixed. Updated packages should arrive soon!

Comment: Scrolling to the top on refresh in gwibber has been fixed for a while in the 2.31 series (Maverick). Hopefully we get 2.32 into backports for Lucid.